# Integrate RSA SecurID to web application without running RSA Authentication Manager

Tags: java, rsa, securid

I am absolutely new to RSA SecurID. I have to use it for authentication in a Java web application. Is it possible to do so by creating an appropriate database structure, using jar files and configuration provided by RSA or I have to install the standalone RSA Authentication Manager application and access it by using appropriate API when I want to authenticate users (or handle token registrations etc)?

I work in Windows environment. If running RSA Authentication Manager is inevitable, only Windows 2003 and 2008 servers are OK to run the app? There are no workarounds? This document says that:
http://www.rsa.com/products/securid/datasheets/11575_h9052_amsp_ds_0312.pdf

I know about other token type from another vendor which can be handled by simply using some jars in my application, for the first look it suprised me that it seems I have to run a windows server and a robust application on it for even to do some 'getting started' testing with RSA SecurID..

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need RSA SecurID Authentication Engine (SAE) APIs. SAE is the ideal solution for organizations that have functions for user management, security policy, password management, and reporting built into their applications. You can just call these API to validate the token.

[Details can be found here](http://www.emc.com/security/rsa-securid/rsa-securid-authentication-engine.htm#!details)